# Rendering menus as Jade view partials in Express

Tags: node.js, view, menu, express, pug

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to render menus with active states in an Express app using Jade view partials.

I have something like this:

```
ul.menu
  li
    a(href='/some/route').active
  li
    a(href='/another/route')
```

What I'd like is for the `.active` class to be applied to the current route, so my CSS can render an active UI state.

When I wrote in PHP, this would've been accomplished through some complex chain of `if/else`, statements, but I'm assuming there's a more elegant approach. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jade is ignorant about the route. I don't think there's any way to avoid the if/else in one form or another.

In Express, just pass the route as a local:

```
res.render('my_view', {
  current: 'current/url'
});
```

And in the view, have an array of menu links and do something like:

```
ul.menu
  for each item in links
    li
      if (item.url == current)
         a(href=item.url).active
      else
         a(href=item.url)
```

Comment: Passing var to every view is little bit crazy, you can try dynamic helper to fix it

Answer (score 8):

My solution is similar to danmactough's, but I think a little tidier.

I use middleware to save the url as a local variable on all requests. Make sure this comes before your routes.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.url = req.url;
  next();
});
```

My Jade template for a menu looks like this

```
ul
  each link in links
    li
      a(href=link.url, class=link.url === url && 'active')= link.name
```